# Teams Popout chat through coding

Tags: microsoft-teams

I want to open the teams chat as pop out chat instead of opening in the chat window. When I used the below code through SPFx, I am able to open the chat window

```
window.open('MSTeams:/l/chat/0/0?users=' + userID, 'popup', 'width=600,height=600,resizable=yes,fullscreen=no');
return false;
```

but I want to open the chat window as pop out chat.
I tried

```
MSTeams:/l/chat/pop/1/0?users=useremail
```

and

```
MSTeams:/l/chat/1/1?users=useremail
```

but its not working please help me on this.

Comment: Yes I am also looking for this. It shall be possible since from Outlook visit card the chat icon open a popped-out chat. See https://tdalon.blogspot.com/2020/09/teams-link-to-1-1-chat-or-call.html#point5

Answer (score 1):

Teams has inbuilt pop out chat feature, there is no official sample code or support available for custom apps. I've raised a Feature request in backlog item.

Comment: Could you link or share your feature request/uservoice or are you from Microsoft and you raised one internally?

Comment: Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience, some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, Please raise a Teams UserVoice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) and vote for it.